# Asterisk search does not find text with question marks

Tags: search

In gvim normal mode, the `*` key searches for the word under the cursor.

Say I have a file with the following lines:

```
life
alifexea a_life_xea
a life x
a=life
life=a
b=life;
c=b?life:a;
life?
?life
```

The cursor is in first line. I press `*` in normal mode. I expect and want all "life" to get highlighted except the 2nd line which has "alifexea a_life_xea". But it doesn't highlight the last 3 lines since the `?` is probably considered a normal character. If I search using `/life` then all lines get highlighted which I do not want. Is there a way around (some setting) to make sure my expectation is satisfied when I search using `*`?.

Comment: What output do you get from this command? `:se isk?`

Comment: I get the following `iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255`

Comment: Hmmm... That's really strange. I can not reproduce this behavior, *unless* I specifically add `?` to the `iskeyword` option, which is about what I'd expect. But if you do not have `?` in your `iskeyword` option, then it should work fine for you. Could you post your `.vimrc`?

Comment: Thanks. You are correct. I checked it on another machine and it works as expected. My .vimrc(copied from some website) is huge. I will try to debug tomorrow and get back if the issue persists.

Comment: You can use `:verbose` to see where an option was last set. e.g. `:verbose set isk?`. See `:h :set-verbose` for more help.

Comment: `:verbose set isk?` returned /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/verilog.vim and this file overrides my .vimrc. This gets sourced only for .sv file extension. I don't know why. Is there a way to override the isk setting?

Comment: @DJMCMayhem sorry I posted :se isk? for an empty file. With a .sv extension file (where the problem occurs) it is different as given in the above comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from your `isk` setting. This tells vim what is considered part of a word and what isn't, which is important for the asterisk command since searches for the word under the cursor. If `isk` includes `?` or `63` (The code point of `?`), then `?` is treated just like letters, so `life` is a different word from `life?` just as `lifex` would be different.

By default, the setting of `isk` is `"@,48-57,_,192-255"`. Which doesn't include `?`. However, if you open up a new file with the `.sv` extension, and you have `filetype plugin on`, then vim will know what kind of file `.sv` is. Presumably, in this type of file, `?` are treated different with this filetype, so vim adds it to `isk`.

To get around this, add the following line to your `.vimrc`:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.sv set isk=@,48-57,_,192-255,#
```

Comment: For .sv file.  `iskeyword=@,48-57,63,_,192-255` As you mentioned since 63 is present the issue is coming. filetype plugin is on. However it is strange that vim assumed it that way for .sv and related files(verilog). In verilog language(like say c language) we cannot define variable as `life?x` but we can define `life_x`. So it makes sense not to put ? as part of the isk. Anyway thanks your workaround works(I didn't add #).

Comment: What is `.sv` filetype? Why do not work the question mark in all file, when trying to regex search? Why does not work asterisk in vim as wild char?